# How can I get the value of the error during training in Tensorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow

In the TensorFlow MNIST beginners tutorial, code excerpts here:

```
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

#-----training loop starts here-----
for i in range(1000):
    batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
```

Is it possible to access/retrieve the values of the cross_entropy error, Weights, and biases while inside the loop? I want to plot the error, and possibly a histogram of the weights.

Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at [TensorBoard](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/how_tos/summaries_and_tensorboard/index.html#tensorboard-visualizing-learning).

Answer (score 4):

As some person say, TensorBoard is the one for that purpose.

Here I can give you how to.

First, let's define a function for logging min, max, mean and std-dev for the tensor.

```
def variable_summaries(var, name):

  with tf.name_scope("summaries"):
    mean = tf.reduce_mean(var)
    tf.scalar_summary('mean/' + name, mean)

    with tf.name_scope('stddev'):
      stddev = tf.sqrt(tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(var - mean)))

    tf.scalar_summary('stddev/' + name, stddev)
    tf.scalar_summary('max/' + name, tf.reduce_max(var))
    tf.scalar_summary('min/' + name, tf.reduce_min(var))
    tf.histogram_summary(name, var)
```

Then, create a summarize operation after you build a graph like below.
This code saves weight and bias of first layer with cross-entropy in "mnist_tf_log" directory.

```
variable_summaries(W_fc1, "W_fc1")
variable_summaries(b_fc1, "b_fc1")
tf.scalar_summary("cross_entropy:", cross_entropy)

summary_op = tf.merge_all_summaries()
summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter("mnist_tf_log", graph_def=sess.graph)
```

Now you're all set.
You can log those data by returning summary_op and pass it to summary_writer.

Here is an example for logging every 10 training steps.

```
for i in range(1000):
    batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(100)
    if i % 10 == 0:
        _, summary_str = sess.run( [train_step, summary_op], feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
        summary_writer.add_summary(summary_str, i)
        summary_writer.flush()
    else:
        sess.run( train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})
```

Execute TensorBoard after you run the code.

```
python /path/to/tensorboard/tensorboard.py --logdir=mnist_tf_log
```

Then you can see the result by opening http://localhost:6006 with your web browser.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tensorboard is made exactly for that:
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/how_tos/summaries_and_tensorboard/index.html